# Выкаченные данные не загружаются в собственную базу данных mysql. В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: mysql, vkontakte-api, загрузка

уважаемые специалисты!

Работаю над программой выгрузки из api vk названий стран и их загрузки в собственную базу данных mysql. Данные из api выгружаются, потому что print_r() дает массив:  [id] => 5 [title] => Азербайджан ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 21 [title] => Албания ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 22 [title] => Алжир ) и т.д., а вот загрузка в базу на локальном сервере не происходит.. Интерпретатор пишет ошибку (Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null) на этом участке кода:

```
public function select_all($sql, $types= null, $params= null) {
        $sql = $this->replace($sql, $types, $params);
        $return = array();
        print_r($return);
        $results = $this->query($sql);
        while ($result = $results->fetch_assoc()) {         
            $return[] = $result;
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

print_r ($return) дает следующее: db Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23 $ [client_version] => 50012 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 0 [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.5.5-10.3.13-MariaDB-log [server_version] => 100313 [stat] => Uptime: 6791 Threads: 8 Questions: 1236 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 19 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 13 Queries per second avg: 0.182 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 202 [warning_count] => 0 ) Ошибка №0

Ошибка №0 - отсутствие ошибок, но количество строк - 0..

Если подняться еще выше, то тут тоже вроде бы ошибки быть не может:

```
private function replace($sql, $types, $params) {
        if (!$types || !$params) {
            return $sql;
        }
```

Подключение к базе точно работает, потому что если сделать к ней простой запрос о загрузке конкретных цифр и слов в колонки, а не массива, то все работает хорошо..

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка? Почему загрузка в базу не происходит..? (

Comment: Загрузка в базу осуществляется так:$counties = Vk::getCountry();
print_r($counties);
$c = Helper::db()->select_all($sql);
if(isset($counties->response->items)) {
    foreach($counties->response->items as $c) {
        echo "{$c->id} - {$c->title}\n";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO country(id,name) VALUES (?,?)";
    
    Helper::db()->insert($sql, "is",[
        $c->id,
        $c->title,
    ]);
        die;
    }
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сработал такой код:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/config.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/db.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/helper.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/request.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/vk.php";

$counties = Vk::getCountry();

var_dump($counties->response->items[1]->{'id'});
var_dump($counties->response->items[1]->{'title'});
$arr = "INSERT INTO country(id,name) VALUES ($arr[id],$arr[title])";

foreach($counties->response->items as $c) {
    $d = $c->title;
    $v = $c->id;


    $sql = "INSERT INTO country (id,name) VALUES ('?', '?')";
    echo "{$c->title}";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO country(id,name) VALUES (?,?)";

    Helper::db()->insert($sql, "is",[
        $c->id,
        $c->title,
    ]);
}
```

Похоже, я просто обошел проблему, оригинальный код подключал функцию из другого файла, а я взял переменную $counties, в которую укладывались данные из vk api и более простым (доступным мне способом) загрузил инфу в таблицу mysql